# Xcode 6 how to disable "Lost connection to iPhone" message when unplugging a device?

Tags: iphone, debugging, ios8, xcode6

Upon upgrading to Xcode 6 every time I unplug a device that is running an app deployed and started from Xcode, I get the application-wide popup box saying "Lost connection to [device name]".

The Xcode icon starts to bounce in the deck and I have to go there and click "OK", otherwise it keeps bouncing, which is really annoying.

[image: Lost connection ss]
After closing that dialog box over 50 times, I have to ask:

Is there a way for me to disable the "Lost connection to [device name]" message in Xcode 6?

I may be running half a dozen demo projects on a device and don't want to have to close all of them before I unplug the device.

Comment: Omg I hate this message so much! What were they thinking?!

Comment: Did somebody figure it out by now?

Comment: Xcode 10 and still it bounces. For me the bouncing Icon is a bad user experience; It draws my attention away from what I am busy with. Very annoying!!

Comment: I scrolled below this question with hope. 

Comment: This still is the most aggravating UI/UX sin that has ever been committed. I'm developing a game that relies on accelerometer control, and I have to unplug the device every time I want to reasonably test the app. Absolutely every time, this message pops up, blocks Xcode, and I have to do an unnecessary click.

Answer (score 0):

which is Xcode 12. However, if you are using Xcode 6, you might be able to disable the "Lost connection to iPhone" message by doing the following:

Open Xcode.
Go to the Preferences menu (Xcode > Preferences or Command + Comma).
Go to the Devices tab.
Uncheck the "Show Disconnect Alerts" option.
This will disable the "Lost connection to iPhone" message when you unplug an iOS device from your Mac.

Note: If you are using Xcode 6 and are having issues with the iOS Simulator, you might want to try resetting the iOS Simulator or deleting the app that you are testing from the iOS Simulator.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).